# Read input value from console/cli at the moment of the question

Tags: php, input, console, buffer, stdin

I've a problem reading input commands from a console application made in php.

**PROBLEM**

If a user using console for mistake press two or more times *ENTER* or some chars, while process is loading, the command is read before ask the question then skipping the next one.

I tried these methods for catch input value but I find everytime the same issue:

```
fgets(STDIN);
readline("Question: ");
stream_get_line(STDIN, 1024, "\n");
```

*Code Example:*

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++){
    $read = readline("Question $i: "); // Look at the number
    echo "Your answer is: " . $read . PHP_EOL;
    sleep(2); // Now on execution try press ENTER one ore more times
}
```

**ATTEMPTS**

I tried this but this method doesn't work on buffers (I tried anyways for be sure):

```
$handle = fopen('php://stdin', 'r+');
ftruncate($handle, 0);
rewind($handle);
fclose($handle);
$read = readline("Question: ");
```

**QUESTION**

How i can read and wait for input at the moment of question display discarding the previous input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I've resolved as follow:

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++){
    /* BEGIN: SOLUTION */
    // Read/Clean buffer until isn't empty
    while(stream_select($read = [STDIN], $write = [], $except = [], 0)){
      fgets(STDIN);
    }
    /* END: SOLUTION */
    $read = readline("Question $i: "); // Look at the number
    echo "Your answer is: " . $read . PHP_EOL;
    sleep(2); // Now on execution try press ENTER one ore more times
}
```